# rails webpacker.yml not found, why this is showing in new setup application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, webpacker

This is just a simple but manual solution at my end.

Actually, I don't debug much and just tried to create a **webpacker.yml** file in the **config** directory like `config/webpacker.yml` and paste the content of **webpacker.yml** of **official rails gem**.

The link is here.
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/install/config/webpacker.yml

And it worked for me. Still, I am trying to find out why ROR setup can't pull this file at the time of Installation!

Can anyone help me to figure out why this is happening in the new setup application?